# SQL Parameterised column names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create a parameterised query for retrieving data back from a table

Essentially I have a table structure of 
ID
nvarchar1
ntext
datetime1
datetime2

and I am trying to do a query like so that it selects all the data where the current date is greater than datetime1 and less than datetime2

```
SELECT 
    ID, nvarchar1, 
    ntext, 
    datetime1, 
    datetime2 
FROM 
    TABLEName 
WHERE 
    datetime1 >= @CurrentDate 
    AND datetime2 <= @CurrentDate
```

I want to make the columns parameters such as 
@TableName, @CurrentDate, @StartDate, @EndDate

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100);
SET @TableName = '[Surveys].[dbo].[Table]'

DECLARE @CurrentDate DateTime;
SET @CurrentDate = GETDATE();

DECLARE @StartDate NVARCHAR(100);
SET @StartDate = 'datetime1'

DECLARE @EndDate NVARCHAR(100);
SET @EndDate = 'datetime2'

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName + 'WHERE' + @EndDate + '>=' + @CurrentDate + 'AND' +  @StartDatedatetime1 + '<=' + @CurrentDate
EXEC(@sql)
```

The data is going to be coming from a SP data source so I have no control of the column names etc. and when I create the SP Lists they automatically assign to a table column of that type so this is why I need to columns to be parameters.

Using the above code which I thought should work returns

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: You shouldn't need quotes for the variables of type datetime. ICBW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below. As @GordonLinoff stated, you where missing the single quotes (`'`) from around the `@CurrentDate` variable. Also, you where passing a `DATETIME` parameter in to the `@sql` variable which is an `NVARCHAR` data type. These are not implicitly converted, so the `@CurrentDate` variable needs to be converted to a `NVARCHAR` first:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName 
    + ' WHERE ' + @EndDate + ' >= ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @CurrentDate,120) 
    + ''' AND ' +  @StartDate + ' <= ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), @CurrentDate,120) + ''''


EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: If you look on Gordons answer you see, that the parameter is passed in without conversion and it's stated in the querie's text without quotes... The usage of parameters is meant to **avoid** literally given values in the query. Secondly: Especially when dealing with datetime values one should avoid conversions if ever possible (if unavoidable prefer `126`).

Comment: The result of this is one column unnamed with the value ---- SELECT * FROM [Surveys].[dbo].[z_TEST] WHERE datetime2 >= '2016-04-20 13:24:25' AND datetime1 <= '2016-04-20 13:24:25' ----- Seems like it it getting closer but not quite there?

Comment: Should the CurrentDate variable be set as a DateTime and should the StartDate and EndDate be DateTime's or should they be nvarchar and converted in the select statement?

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks for the comment. I was dealing with the error that klydemonroe was receiving. Gordon's answer is how I would approach the situation. But it didn't address the reason for the error and anybody receiving the same error in similar circumstances wouldn't find reference to solving it.

Comment: @KlydeMonroe Aren't the `@StartDate` & `@EndDate` variables supposed to reference column names for the table held in the `@TableName` variable?

Comment: @BeaglesEnd - Yes the @ StartDate = datetime1 and @ EndDate = datetime2

Comment: @BeaglesEnd I have managed to get this to work it was the SELECT @ sql needed to be EXEC @ sql

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty close.  I would construct the SQL for the table and then use parameters for the current date:  This would be something like this:

```
SET @sql = '
SELECT *
FROM @TableName
WHERE datetime2 >= @CurrentDate AND datetime1 <= @CurrentDate';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@TableName', @TableName);

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@CurrentDate date', @CurrentDate = @CurrentDate;
```

Incidentally, the problem with your query is the lack of single quotes around the date constants.

EDIT:

You cannot substitute column or table names using parameters.  I would write the code as:

```
SET @sql = '
SELECT *
FROM @TableName
WHERE @datetime2 >= @CurrentDate AND @datetime1 <= @CurrentDate';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@TableName', @TableName);
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@datetime1', @DateTime1);
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@datetime2', '@DateTime2);
```

. . .

I use `REPLACE()` for this type of operation because the code is easier to understand and to maintain.

Comment: I am not sure I understand ... I have got it working as below...                           DECLARE @ CurrentDate DateTime;
SET @ CurrentDate = GETDATE();

SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
      ,[nvarchar1]
      ,[ntext2]
      ,[datetime1]
      ,[datetime2]
FROM [Surveys].[dbo].[z_TEST]
WHERE datetime2 >= @ CurrentDate
AND datetime1 <= @ CurrentDate                                                        But as soon as I try convert the datetime1 and datetime2 to params it fails - Spaces in the variable intentional for commenting